# Writing custom OpenGL ES 2.0 Shader / MatrixHandler, getting blank screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to write my own shader class and matrix handling class for an android application using GLES20. However, right now I'm only getting the background color.

I've been pulling my hair out over this for a couple of days. I wanted to compare matrix operations between my class and GL10 stuff to make sure they spit out the same results, but I couldn't for the life of me get the api example MatrixGrabber and MatrixTrackingGL to spit anything out besides the identity matrix (despite rendering correctly).

So I'm going to post some code, and please let me know if you see anything that could be the problem in these two classes!

Here is my MatrixHandler class:

```
import java.util.Stack;

import android.opengl.Matrix;

public class MatrixHandler
{
    public static float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    public static float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];
    public static float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    public static float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

    public static Stack<float[]> mvpStack = new Stack<float[]>();
    public static Stack<float[]> projStack = new Stack<float[]>();
    public static Stack<float[]> viewStack = new Stack<float[]>();
    public static Stack<float[]> rotationStack = new Stack<float[]>();

    public static void setViewIdentity()
    {
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mViewMatrix, 0);
    }

    public static void setProjIdentity()
    {
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mProjMatrix, 0);
    }

    public static void setViewport(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far)
    {
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0,
                left, right,
                bottom, top,
                near, far
            );
    }

    public static void setLookAt(
            float eyeX, float eyeY, float eyeZ,
            float posX, float posY, float posZ,
            float upX, float upY, float upZ
        )
    {
        Matrix.setLookAtM(
                mViewMatrix, 0,

                eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ,
                posX, posY, posZ,
                upX, upY, upZ
            );

        //Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    }

    public static void translate(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        Matrix.translateM(mViewMatrix, 0,
                x, y, z
            );
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    }

    public static void rotate(float a, float x, float y, float z)
    {
        Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0,
                a, x, y, z
            );
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    }

    public static void pushMatrix()
    {
        mvpStack.push(mMVPMatrix);
        projStack.push(mProjMatrix);
        viewStack.push(mViewMatrix);
        rotationStack.push(mRotationMatrix);
    }

    public static void popMatrix()
    {
        mMVPMatrix = mvpStack.pop();
        mProjMatrix = projStack.pop();
        mViewMatrix = viewStack.pop();
        mRotationMatrix = rotationStack.pop();
    }

    public static void printMatrix(String label, float[] m)
    {
        System.err.print(label + " : {");
        for(float i : m)
        {
            System.err.print(i + ", ");
        }
        System.err.println("}");
    }
}
```

And here is my Shader class:

```
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import com.bradsproject.appName.MatrixHandler;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

public class Shader
{
    private static int mProgram;

    static int maPositionHandle;
    static int maColorHandle;
    static int maTextureHandle;

    static int muMVPMatrixHandle;

    static int maTexture;

    private final static String mVertexShader =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec3 aPosition;" +
        "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;" +
        "attribute vec4 aColor;" +
        "varying vec4 vColor;" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);" +
        "  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;" +
        "  vColor = aColor;" +
        "}";

    private final static String mFragmentShader =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;" +
            "uniform sampler2D sTexture;" +
            "varying vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);" +
            "}";

    public static void init()
    {
        mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);
        if (mProgram == 0)
            return;

        maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
        maColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aColor");
        maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");

        maTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "sTexture");

        muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    }

    public static void drawArrays(FloatBuffer mPosition, FloatBuffer mColor, FloatBuffer mTexture, int textureId, int mode)
    {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        mPosition.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, mPosition);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);

        mColor.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maColorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 4, mColor);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maColorHandle);

        mTexture.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * 4, mTexture);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(maTexture, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, MatrixHandler.mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(mode, 0, mPosition.capacity() / 3);
    }

    private static int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource)
    {
        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
        if (vertexShader == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to load vertex shader.");
            return 0;
        }

        int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
        if (pixelShader == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to load fragment shader.");
            return 0;
        }

        int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        if (program != 0)
        {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
            int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
            if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE)
            {
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
                program = 0;
            }
        }
        return program;
    }

    private static int loadShader(int shaderType, String source)
    {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
        if (shader != 0)
        {
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
            int[] compiled = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
            if (compiled[0] == 0)
            {
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }
        }
        return shader;
    }

    private static void checkGlError(String op)
    {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually found a few errors. I'll try to post the new source later.

Answer (score 0):

**You are missing "\n" at the end**

**Avoid those matrix stack, soon you will run short of speed with those heavy stuff when your code becomes larger than 1000 lines of code whether it is openglgame or openglapp**

**For speed use const, local variables in shader code and perform more calculations inside the fragment shader**

Here is a shader set

```
private static final String vertexShaderCodeLight = 
        "uniform vec4 uVPosition;                   \n"
    +   "uniform mat4 uP;                           \n"
    +   "void main(){                               \n"
    +   " gl_PointSize = 15.0;                      \n"
    +   " gl_Position = uP * uVPosition;            \n"
    +   "}                                          \n";
private static final String fragmentShaderCodeLight = 
        "#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH          \n"
    +   "precision highp float;                     \n"
    +   "#else                                      \n"
    +   "precision mediump float;                   \n"
    +   "#endif                                     \n"
    +   "void main(){                               \n"
    +   " gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);     \n"
    +   "}                                          \n";
```